# Isometry definition

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I work in holography and I'm trying to get my feet when in non-relativistic holography. Can someone explain exactly what an "isometry" is in this context?

"the correspondence can be extended to a non-relativistic holography by taking background geometries in General Relativity that have non-relativistic isometries like Schrödinger or Lifshitz symmetries, which are the typical symmetries of a wide class of field theories describing non-relativistic phenomena."

My knowledge is this: in group theory, two groups are homomorphic,
in topology, two spaces are homeomorphic, and in geometry, two geometries are isometric. My topology instructor said this once, but I have no formal geometry instruction outside of a GR course and so don't fully understand it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) is a transformation that preserves metric, as is obvious from the word itself.

And I believe that the quote in your question contains a typo. The phrase should be read as

> … geometries in General Relativity that have non-relativistic isometries-like Schrödinger or Lifshitz symmetries …

(*Note the dash*). So the “isometries-like symmetries” are the symmetries that are *similar* to isometries in their role, but are *not actually* isometries. That makes much more sense since Schrödinger [1] and Lifshitz [2] symmetries are symmetries of a field theory but not of the metric (since they include time and space coordinate scaling transformation).

1. D. Son, “*Toward an AdS/cold atoms correspondence: A Geometric realization of
   the Schrodinger symmetry*,” [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.78.046003),
   [arXiv:0804.3972](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3972).
2. S. Kachru, X. Liu, and M. Mulligan, “*Gravity Duals of Lifshitz-like Fixed Points*,” [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.78.106005), [arXiv:0808.1725](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1725).